# Sort AWS IOT shadow values from dynamodb

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using **AWS IOT Thing**. I have created a rule to my thing something like below

```
{
 "rule": {
 "ruleDisabled": false,
 "sql": "SELECT * AS message FROM 'some/topic'",
 "description": "A test Dynamo DB rule",
 "actions": [{
 "dynamoDB": {
 "hashKeyField": "key",
 "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/aws_iot_dynamoDB",
 "tableName": "my_ddb_table",
 "hashKeyValue": "${topic()}",
 "rangeKeyValue": "${timestamp()}",
 "rangeKeyField": "timestamp"
 }
 }]
 }
}
```

I was successful in inserting iot values to my table.

Now **i need to take all values from my table in order of timestamp in ascending order**.

I tried **dynamodb query**, but requires primary key in it. I cannot use primary key in my case because i need all values, not specific key.

I also tried **dynamodb scan**, but it does not have sorting feature

**Does any one any idea?**

Comment: Well, you can add a [GSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html), with a fixed hash key and the timestamp as a range key. You will then be able to perform a query on the GSI using the known fixed hash key value.

Comment: You will need to scan and perform the sort yourself, unless you create a GSI as Matias says.